# Find all polynomials P such that $P(x) | P(x^2)$

Tags: polynomials

If $x$ is the root of $P$, then $x^2$ is also the root. Now spamming this we get that $x^{2^k}$ is eventually $1$ for fixed root $x$ (and some positive integer k, of course assuming that $x \ne 0$). But thats where i got stuck.

Comment: There are multiple polynomials of every degree that satisfy this relation and they are difficult to list explicitly. Are the polynomials allowed to have complex coefficients?

Comment: I don't think $x^{2^k}$ must necessarily be 1; for example, $P(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ satisfies the condition and the sequence $x^{2^k}$ is periodic instead of eventually constant.  (Also, there's the case of a root of 0 - $P(x) = x$ works, for example.)  So, the fact $P$ has finitely many roots means $(x^{2^k})_{k=0}^\infty$ must eventually have repeated entries, so any root is either 0 or a root of unity.

Comment: On the other hand, I think any cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ should work if $n$ is odd; and similarly any product of such cyclotomic polynomials.  I don't know if that would cover all possible solutions.

Comment: Oh, wait, if complex coefficients are allowed (rather than just rational coefficients) then I think $P(x) = (x - e^{2\pi i/7}) (x - e^{4\pi i/7}) (x - e^{8\pi i/7})$ would work, and it's not a product of cyclotomic polynomials.